# como puedo ordenar los numeros decimales con el siguiente orden si son de tipo varchar en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, orderby, sqldatatypes

Quiero ordenar los siguientes numeros :

> 1.1,
> 1.10,
> 1.11,
> 1.12,
> 1.2,
> 1.3

para que queden así:

> 1.1,
> 1.2,
> 1.3,
> 1.10,
> 1.11,
> 1.12

el tipo de dato es varchar

Comment: que haz intentado?, por favor agregalo

Answer (score 3):

Que tal si quitamos el punto con replace y ordenamos.

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE (Texto varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Tabla VALUES ('1.1'),('1.10'),('1.11'),('1.12'),('1.2'),('1.3')
SELECT Texto FROM @Tabla order by CONVERT(int,REPLACE(Texto,'.','')) ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Habría que iniciar por separar los valores para poder trabajarlos. Esto se puede conseguir con la función `string_split()`, que devuelve un conjunto de filas.

A partir de este resultado, puedes construir una expresión por la cual ordenar en la cláusula `group by`.

Ya que veo que para ordenar solamente tomas en cuenta el *número* que está después del caracter '.', puedes construir una expresión en la cual obtener la cadena que está después del mismo e interpretarlo como número.

Por ejemplo:

```
with 
Base(sNum) as (
select value from string_split('1.1,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.2,1.3', ',')
)
select sNum
  from Base
 order by try_cast(substring(sNum, charindex('.', sNum) + 1, 300) as int)
```

Devuelve como resultado:

```
sNum
--------------------------
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.10
1.11
1.12

(6 rows affected)
```

La expresión del group by:

- Determina la posición del punto decimal con `charindex()`
- Extrae todos los caracteres que están después de dicha posición, con `substring()` — asumiendo que la cadena tiene menos de 300 caracteres de longitud.
- Intenta interpretar este valor como un número entero, con `try_cast()`

Dado que necesitas una cadena, puedes utilizar la expresión `for xml` para lograr la concatenación de los resultados:

```
select ',' + sNum
  from Base
 order by try_cast(substring(sNum, charindex('.', sNum) + 1, 300) as int)
   for xml path('')
```

Como ves, le *sobra* una coma al inicio. Para removerla, finalmente, puedes utilizar la función `stuff()`.

Poniendo todas las piezas juntas:

```
with 
Base(sNum) as (select value from string_split('1.1,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.2,1.3', ','))
select stuff(
           (select ',' + sNum from Base order by try_cast(substring(sNum, charindex('.', sNum) + 1, 300) as int) for xml path(''))
         , 1, 1, '') as CadenaOrdenada
```

Te devuelve una cadena ordenada como la necesitas:

```
CadenaOrdenada
--------------------------------
1.1,1.2,1.3,1.10,1.11,1.12

(1 row affected)
```