# Como ordenar numeros con puntos en SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reportviewer

tengo un reporte en SQL Server Reporting Services, en el cual tengo un campo que debería ordenar varios detalles por numero, por ejemplo: 1.1, 1.1.3, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2.3, 3.4, etc.
este campo es tipo string y mi problema es que a la hora de ordenar toma solo el primer valor y los demás los omite Y queda así:
1.1,
11,
2
Como puedo solucionar este problema?.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es que tome el primer valor, es que trata el dato como cadena, dependiendo de los datos que tengas se me ocurren varias estrategias, pero mínimamente debería agregar a tu pregunta algún ejemplo variado de datos y la consulta que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: ya modifique la pregunta y si, el problema es que trate el dato como una cadena como vos decís, por eso ordena solamente tomando en cuenta el primer digito, si fuera solo un punto seria fácil de convertir a decimal pero también hay números con varios puntos como 1.2.3, no se si eso se podrá convertir a decimal.

Comment: Sin tener una muestra de los distintos tipos de datos, la respuesta siempre va a ser incompleta, mirá si siempre hay un digito entre cada punto, podrías tranquilamente eliminar los puntos de la cadena y ordenar, ahora si la cantidad de digitos entre cada punto es variable, se requiere una solución más inteligente dividiendo la cadena en varias columnas y ordenar por cada una de ellas.

Answer (score -1):

Existe una función ABS() que quizás cumpla con tu objetivo.

ó

> Que tal si quitamos el punto con replace y ordenamos.
>
> ```
> DECLARE @Tabla TABLE (Texto varchar(10))
> INSERT INTO @Tabla VALUES ('1.1'),('1.10'),('1.11'),('1.12'),('1.2'),('1.3')
> SELECT Texto FROM @Tabla order by CONVERT(int,REPLACE(Texto,'.','')) ASC
> ```

Ref.: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/452035/70086